# SQL SERVER connection problems

Tags: sql-server, connection

I have just gotten a windows 7 new box and have SQL Server 2005 installed. I get the following error when trying to connect to my local instance using windows authentication:

Cannot connect to CHRISW70980.

Additional information:
Login failed for user 'MPRINC.COM\chrisw'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

I've looked online and turned off Windows 7 firewall, made sure the TCP was enabled on 1433 in the SQL Server configuration manager, and the SQL server configuration manager says the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) is running and set to automatic.

Oh yeah, the error dialog box happens to appear immediately too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's local to your machine then firewall and TCP won't have anything to do with it. Since the server is telling you the login failed you can obviously reach the database. My guess - you aren't a member of a group who has access to the database instance.

If you can, put yourself in the local administrators group and try connecting again.

Comment: how do i do add myself to the local administrators group?

Comment: Start > Control Panel > User Accounts > User Accounts > Manage User Accounts. Select your user name, click Properties. In Group Membership tab select the Administrators radio button. Confirm all open dialogs.

Comment: okay you were right, i had to add myself as the mssql group.  now i just need to figure out how to be part of multiple groups.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server Management Studio, you could try right-clicking the icon and selecting Run As Administrator to launch the application. Apart from that you could sign in with a SQL account (e.g. "sa") if you set up mixed mode authentication when you installed SQL Server.

Comment: @Yuck I know you have to Run As Administrator if you're using Named Pipes, but I didn't think it was necessary for a TCP connection. (But then again, it may be trying to use Named Pipes for some reason.)

Comment: how do you add yourself as multiple groups too?

Comment: okay cool thanks @Yuck, i have it all running and working now

Answer (score 1):

This means that you have the wrong password (or username).
(Or your account ddoesn't have access to the database you're connecting to)

The connection itself is working fine; otherwise, you'd get a timeout of a different error.

Comment: how do i change the password and username when using windows authentication? was the sql server installed correctly?